# Why does Verilog invert the first bit of a 4 bit variable?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to code something in verilog but for some reason the value I enter changes when I print it out

This is my code

```
module test;
reg [3:0] A;
reg [3:0] B;
initial
     begin
       $monitor("%b %b",A,B);
       $display("A    B");
          A=0000; B=0000; 
       #1 A=0001; B=0001; 
       #1 A=0111; B=0111;
       #1 A=0011; B=1011; 
     end
endmodule
```

For Some reason it prints this

> A      B
>
> 0000 0000
>
> 0001 0001
>
> 1111 1111
>
> 1011 0011

Comment: You are assigning *decimal values* to your regs, which truncates them to the 4-bit size of the reg.  `0011` is simply eleven; the value with the two low bits set could be written `4'b0011`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the notation 4'b followed by the number to specify a 4-bit binary literal in Verilog.

```
module test;
reg [3:0] A;
reg [3:0] B;
initial
     begin
       $monitor("%b %b",A,B);
       $display("A    B");
          A=4'b0000; B=4'b0000; 
       #1 A=4'b0001; B=4'b0001; 
       #1 A=4'b0111; B=4'b0111;
       #1 A=4'b0011; B=4'b1011; 
     end
endmodule
```